# Linux Bash Script: How to get file without path?

Tags: linux, bash, path, ls

I am trying to write a very very simple script in Linux.
Let me show you the code first:

```
#!/bin/bash
# The shell program uses glob constructs and ls
# to list all entries in testfiles, that have 2
# or more dots "." in their name.

ls -l /path/to/file/*.*.*
```

When I run this code with `bash myscript` command, I get something like: /path/to/file/file.with.three.dots

But I don't want this. I want to show only the file name, not the path.
Then I tried:

```
ls -l *.*.*
```

But this time is shows me the files, only if I am inside the /path/to/file/.
How can I set the path, so when running the script from any place, it will output the name of the files in the /path/to/file/?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to use the `realpath` command like `p=$(realpath foo/bar)`

Comment: Edited; the title of your question asked the exact opposite of what you want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`basename path/to/file.b.c` should give you file.b.c

However re-reading the question, I think a temporary `cd` to the path and then an `ls` may be better:

```
(cd /path/to/file; ls -l *.*.*)
```

Comment: So just write `ls -l basename /path/to/file/*.*.*` ?

Comment: The base name command will give you just the filename from a path. Sounds like you want `(cd /path/to/file; ls -l *.*.*)`

Comment: I have now `cd /path/to/file/; ls -l *.*.*`. It works as expected, only if I run `bash myscript` from inside the /path/to/file

Comment: @m.spyratos: The `()` around the command are important. Don't omit them.

Comment: @John3136: Wouldn't `{ cd ... ; }` be better?

Comment: @AaronDigulla, using `()` instead of `{}` does not have any side-effects: when the subshell ends, the effects of the `cd` vanish.

Comment: I am pretty sure I tried it with `()` too. I will try it again today and will let you know! Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Code first:

```
ls -l /path/to/file/*.*.* | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'
```

Now explanation: You list file of your choice and then use awk on it. Switch -F will determine character you use for split (/ in this case). Then you print with awk the value of "$NF", which means "the last one". So you have: /path/to/file/file.with.three.dots. Split it, take the last one (file.with.three.dots) and print it (regardless how long/deep is your path) and without any need of changing your current position on file system.

I really hope, I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use the find command.

```
$> find /path/to/file -printf %f\\n\\r
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sticking with basename.

```
ls -1 /path/to/file/*.*.* | while read path
do
    basename "$path"
done
```

Its best to use *while read* rather than *for path in $(ls /path/*)* only because if your paths happen to have a space in them the for loop will segment the path.

Comment: Actually, it's best to use a for loop: `for path in /path/to/file/*.*.*.; do ...`

Comment: But the for loop will break if the glob patterns have a space in them.

Comment: It will not: that's the magic of using a for loop to iterate over a glob pattern. If you did `for file in $(ls)`, that *will* break on spaces.

Comment: Nice, but I found I needed to put quotes around the pathname, `ls -1 "$1" | while read path` to accommodate spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation on Zapatero's technique to capture the base file name in an environment variable. `$1` is the command-line argument that, by definition in my script, is the full path to the filename in question.

Note that if the full path contains wildcards and returns multiple results, the basename variable will be set to the "last" matching filename, in whatever order `ls` returns them.

```
basename=$(ls -1 "$1" | while read path; do basename "$path"; done)
```